# Selenium: New Chrome version 113.0.5672.64 driver fails to start

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, driver

I webscrape in Jupiter notebook (Python) using selenium and a chrome driver. With the new chrome version (113.0.5672.64) the driver fails to launch. I have the 113.0.5672.63 chrome driver version. It complaints about a missing chrome_elf.dll in the folder Application/113.0.5672.63. (Using the chrome browser manually works just fine).

How do I fix that? I really need to get the scraper running again. Any help would be highly appreciated!!

I un- and reinstalled chrome already but that didn't help. I also deleted and re-downloaded the chrome driver.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm going thought the same problem. Some people say it's the antivirus removing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing similar errros:

```
Incompatible release of chromedriver (version 113.0.5672.63) detected in PATH: /usr/bin/chromedriver

...


selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 113.0.5672.0 with binary path /usr/bin/chromium
```

Following helped me:

```py
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version="113.0.5672.24").install(), options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work for me. But thank you!